# Frequency Count for Strings

Tags: python, string, count

I have this function that returns the list of values and counts for integer values. I would like to alter this to return the counts and values of strings, as I am having trouble implementing. It works for integer values but not strings.

```
def frequencies(xs):
 ys = sorted(xs)
 values, count = [], []
 for y in ys:
     if y not in values:
         values.append(y)
         count.append(1)
     else:
         count[-1] += 1
 return values, count
```

Comment: Please explain what "having trouble" means.

Comment: I can pass in a column of floats and it returns the two lists, with one being the list of values and the other being the list of the number of times that value appears in the column. I want to be able to do the same for strings. values = [17.0, 18.0, 19.0]
count = [328, 447, 590]. For example, I would like values = ['red','blue','green'] count = [1, 3, 9]

Comment: Works fine for me: `frequencies([1,2,3,2,3,4,5,3,4,3,4,2,1,2,5])` yields `([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 4, 3, 2])`, while `frequencies(["1","2","3","2","3","4","5","3","4",'3','4','2','1','2','5'])` yields `(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], [2, 4, 4, 3, 2])`

Comment: What is wrong with the output you get when passing a list of strings?

Comment: It returns [nan, nan, nan] [1,1,1] for example

Comment: I get `(['blue', 'green', 'red'], [1, 1, 1])`; is it possible that you somehow corrupted `sorted`?  Can you verify what `ys` is?  Can you verify when `xs` is?

Comment: @user3318660 can you provide ur input data???

Answer (score 1):

using `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,3,7,8,4,5,6,3]
>>> [ [x,len(list(y))] for x,y in itertools.groupby(sorted(a))]  # if you want list
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 4], [4, 3], [5, 3], [6, 2], [7, 1], [8, 1]] 
>>> {x:len(list(y)) for x,y in itertools.groupby(sorted(a))}     # if you want dictionary
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 4, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 2, 7: 1, 8: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel, and not use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)? From what I understand, you  try to achieve exactly what Counter does.

```
from collections import  Counter 

a = Counter([1,2,3,2,3,4,5,3,4,3,4,2,1,2,5])
print(a.keys(), a.values())


b = Counter(["1","2","3","2","3","4","5","3","4",'3','4','2','1','2','5'])
print(b.keys(), b.values())
```

Gives:

```
dict_keys([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) dict_values([2, 4, 4, 3, 2])
dict_keys(['4', '2', '3', '1', '5']) dict_values([3, 4, 4, 2, 2])
```

Comment: This returns [1,1,1,1] [nan,nan,nan,nan]

Comment: @user3318660 Your result is for what input? The strings?

Comment: I have a txt file and I am simply passing in a column from that table file

Comment: @user3318660 need example(s) of input data that you have. Otherwise, difficult to understand what you try to do.